# How to use CGRectContainsPoint() with rotated UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have a `UIView`, and the user can tap the `UIView` to 'select' or highlight the in-app 'thing' that it represents. I use `CGRectContainsPoint(thing.frame,tapPoint)` to achieve this, where `thing.frame` is the frame of the `UIView`, and `tapPoint` is the tapped point from a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. This works perfect.

..except when `UIView` is rotated by setting the `transform` property (with a `CGAffineTransform` value). When the `UIView` is rotated like this, the `frame` becomes a flat square that encapsulates the rotated view.

Here is an illustration of the problem (frame property is labeled A, and the visual `UIView` `bounds` are labeled B):

**When NOT Rotated**

```
+------------------+
|      A == B      |
+------------------+
```

**When Rotated**

```
+-----------------+
|  A        .     |
|         .   .   |
|       .       . |
|     .       .   |
|   .    B  .     |
| .       .       |
|   .   .         |
|     .           |
+-----------------+
```

I want to capture taps that are within the bounds of rect `B` (the true bounds of `UIView`, rotated), but NOT when they're only within rect `A` (the value of the `frame` property of `UIView`) and not `B`.

How might I calculate whether a given tap point is within the true bounds/frame/borders of the rotated `UIView`? Is there a convenience method for this? Or would I need to calculate the coordinates and dimensions of `B` using my own geometry?

(If the latter, please include a suggestion so we can make the answer as complete as possible. Thanks!)

Comment: +1 for the way question is formatted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're discovering the one fundamental stumbling block that everybody has when they first work for frame and bounds.

Frame is the smallest possible (non-rotated) rectangle in which a view fits in, taking into account transformation.  Meaning, if you were to test for touches, you could log in the available space around the view so long as it was within that smallest possible rectangle.

For the visual, imagine the blue square is a transformed `UIView`. The blue border around the view represents it's frame.  Notice how, even though the view is transformed, that it's frame remains un-transformed and in standard position.  The green area represents the areas that are touchable if `frame` is passed instead of `bounds`:

[image: frame]

Bounds, on the other hand, represents the reciever's rectangle with respect to itself, taking into account transformations, and so testing for points in the view by passing bounds (after a `-convertPoint:toView:` call) will correctly return whether or not a given touch (point) intersects the view.

Comment: This worked perfectly; I was already down the path of using the bounds, but `convertPoint:toView:` was the key. However, I still don't fully understand the inner-workings of this method.. is it simply applying novel math and working out the true rotated bounds using simple geometry? Or is this doing something with `UIView` that a responsible developer should understand?

Comment: It's really that when you get the frame of a UIView, the framework doesn't actually query the view, instead it queries a ton of other properties and does some quick math to return a result.  Bounds is the true representation of the "frame" of the object.

Comment: But `bounds` still simply displays as (0,0,width,height) - at least its `description` property does. So it sounds like this is not something hidden away somewhere that we can access, but instead something that `UIView` can easily compute on its own. If I've got that right, very good to know, thanks. :)

Comment: Because bounds doesn't take into account the frame in relation to the superview, it's the introspective frame of the view itself.  Ergo, it will always start with (0, 0)

Comment: @toblerpwn The `bounds` of a view are in the view's own coordinate system, not its parent's coordinate system.  when you rotate the view, you rotate its coordinate system also.  The view's frame is really its layer's frame, and the layer computes its frame based on its `position`, `bounds.size`, `anchorPoint`, and `transform`.

Answer (score 4):

here is code, viewB is target view, viewA is source view that containing the point.

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint(viewB.bounds, [viewA convertPoint:point toView:viewB])){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this answer as I wanted a full code response explained. If anyone needs the code, for the sake of completeness, this is how I ended up calculating if a view (containerView) is fully contained in another view (view):

```
-(BOOL)viewIsFullyContained:(UIView*)view{
    // get the inner rectangle corners in the view coordinate system
    CGPoint upperLeft   = [self.containerView convertPoint:self.containerView.bounds.origin toView:view];
    CGPoint upperRight  = [self.containerView convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.containerView.bounds.origin.x + self.containerView.bounds.size.width,
                                                                   self.containerView.bounds.origin.y)
                                                toView:view];
    CGPoint lowerLeft   = [self.containerView convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.containerView.bounds.origin.x,
                                                                   self.containerView.bounds.origin.y + self.containerView.bounds.size.height)
                                                toView:view];
    CGPoint lowerRight  = [self.containerView convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.containerView.bounds.origin.x + self.containerView.bounds.size.width,
                                                                   self.containerView.bounds.origin.y + self.containerView.bounds.size.height)
                                                toView:view];
    // Check whether all of the corners are fully contained in the view.
    BOOL upperLeftIsContained   = CGRectContainsPoint(view.bounds, upperLeft);
    BOOL upperRightIsContained  = CGRectContainsPoint(view.bounds, upperRight);
    BOOL lowerLeftIsContained   = CGRectContainsPoint(view.bounds, lowerLeft);
    BOOL lowerRightIsContained  = CGRectContainsPoint(view.bounds, lowerRight);
    NSLog(@"Checking for (%i/%i/%i/%i)",upperLeftIsContained,upperRightIsContained,lowerLeftIsContained,lowerRightIsContained);
    return (upperRightIsContained && upperRightIsContained && lowerRightIsContained && lowerLeftIsContained);
}
```