# How to get CGRectContainsPoint() to work with bounds of a UIImageView which is rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitouch, cgpoint

I've read a lot of similar question, but could not find the answer I'm looking for.

This post explains al lot:
[How to use CGRectContainsPoint() with rotated UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028811/how-to-use-cgrectcontainspoint-with-rotated-uiview)

My situation: I've got a UIScrollView with a UIImageView which contains a "Full sized image". contentsize == image.size. When I click on the screen another UIImageView is added onto the UIImageView(full-size image). I use this code to determine the position for adding:

```
CGPoint position = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:_imagescrollview];
CGPoint positioninimageview = [_imagescrollview convertPoint:position toView:_editimageview];
```

The UIImageView gets added to a MutableArray. When I click on the screen it detects if a UIImageView is clicked by looping through the MutableArray containing the added UIImageViews. If True -> select the UIImageView for editing else -> add new UIImageView at touched position.

```
- (UIImageView *)getImageViewUnderTouch:(CGPoint)position {
     UIImageView *imageview = nil;

     for (int i = 0; i < [imageviewarray count]; i++) {
        imageview = [imageviewarray objectAtIndex:i];

         if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageview.frame,position)) {
            return imageview;
         }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

All works except when the UIImageView is rotated. The Frame gets larger because the bounds are rotated in that Frame (I get that!). So when you click on the Frame it will return the UIImage, but I don't want that. I want the UIImageVIew to be returned when the tap is within the Bounds of the UIImageView. I've tried a lot especially using convertPoint:..

Somehow I need to transform the position according to the bounds of the UIImageView. It needs to know the frame is rotated.

```
CGPoint positioninbounds = [imageview convertPoint:position toView:_editimageview];
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with rotation? A different UIDeviceOrientation?

Comment: With rotation I mean the rotation of the UIImageView. The Device orientation stays the same.

Comment: So you rotate the UIImageView with a transform? If so, you need to check the frame of the presentationLayer: `imageview.layer.presentationLayer.frame`

Comment: I used this code:    
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(((CALayer*imageview.layer.presentationLayer).frame,positioninbounds)) Which has the same result.